# How did Sorrento know Wade was using emotion suppressing software?

Tags: ready-player-one

How did Sorrento know Wade was using emotion suppressing software?  The hologram in the scene looked the same when he first clicked the prism to enter to when he was talking with Sorrento.  What was the difference that tipped Sorrento off that he was using emotion suppressing software?

Answer (score 3):

Because Wade's avatar didn't show a reaction to the outrageous amount of money that Sorrento just offered him.